# AWS bootstrap AMI with credentials for downloading form a private s3 bucket

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to bootstrap an AMI to download a file from a private S3 bucket.
I've set the credentials correctly and when I try to copy a file from my bucket to my EC2 instance I can see in the system log that it was unable to detect my credentials.
What's weird that when I log to my instance using SSH and using the same command I'm successfully copying my file to my instance.

Here is the bash script for the UserData:

```
#! /bin/bash
yum update -y
sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk -y
sudo yum install java-1.8.0 -y
mkdir -p home/ec2-user/.aws
cat > home/ec2-user/.aws/config << EOF
[default]\n
aws_access_key_id=my_access_key_id\n
aws_secret_access_key=my_secret_key\n
region=eu-west-1
EOF
aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket_name/filename home/ec2-user/filename
```

Thanks,

Comment: You should consider using EC2 Instance Profiles to provide IAM credentials to your instances, instead of configuring credentials in a file like this.

Comment: Even better idea, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your script will only run when the current directory is `/` because:

```
cat > home/ec2-user/...
```

is relative. This will work when you log in and happen to run with `CWD=/`.

I haven't tested it yet but I would suspect cloudinit does not run UserData from /.  You can either prove that by updating the script with a leading / or I can confirm it later.

Comment: Thanks for the response,
The instance is running from the root when bootstrapping, therefor i'm starting "home/ec2-user/...".
The creation of the directories and the config file are being created just fine.
For some reason the execution of the "aws s3 cp ..." gets an error.

Comment: The cloudinit normally runs as root but you want to use ec2-user credentials.  So it will look in root’s Home directory. You can insert su to change user or look for a command line switch or env var to locate the credentials.  E.g. AWS_CONFIG_FILE. There are a few env vars will adjust the cli.

Comment: uh, I see I will give it a try.